# org.w3c.dom.NodeList doesn't extend Iterable

Tags: java, dom

Is there any reason why would authors of Java org.w3c.dom library choose not to support the [Iterable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) interface? For example, the interface [NodeList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html) seems like a perfect fit for extending Iterable.

Comment: Just asked me the same question, org.w3c.dom appeared in JDK 1.4 and Iterator in JDK 1.2. Simple answer is that once again the W3C spec for the Java Binding was made by somebody who never coded (in Java).
The fact NodeList being not iterable and following no convention (what the hell is getLength !!) is really a huge pain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The World Wide Web consortium has defined the [Document Object Model (DOM)](http://www.w3.org/DOM/) as follows:

> The Document Object Model is a **platform- and language-neutral**
>   interface that will allow programs and scripts to dynamically access
>   and update the content, structure and style of documents.

It's implementation for a number of languages look very much like each other, which smart people thought to be a good idea, a lot of years ago when they designed it.
As a result, it doesn't look like anything familiar in any language.

If you want to use an alternative to the w3c DOM that does look like a Java library, use [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/). Or map your XML to Java objects using a mapping/binding solution, such as [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html)

But if you need to interface with existing libraries that already use w3c DOM (like the built-in XSLT and XSD processors), then you're stuck with it. Unfortunately.

---

To @eis:

Yes there is a reason that you can't add an interface such as `Iterable` to `NodeList`, and that reason is that the Java binding of the Document Object Model is defined in [the standard](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). Take `NodeList`, it is 100% defined in the standard. No room for any extra interfaces.

**org/w3c/dom/NodeList.java:**

```
package org.w3c.dom;

public interface NodeList {
    public Node item(int index);

    public int getLength();

}
```

There is no binding in the standard for C#, but there is one for EcmaScript. I believe the the IXMLDocument interfaces that you mention are also used for their EcmaScript implementation (but I could be wrong), in which case they still need to stick to the standard in terms of what methods they support and what the type hierarchy is.

The difference is that the EcmaScript binding only describes which methods should exist, while the Java binding describes the exact method in the interface.
There is no reason though in Java that the class that implements `NodeList` can't implement `Iterable` too. However, if your code depended on that it would not work with the DOM standard, but with a particular implementation only.

Microsoft has never really bothered with this fine distinction since they generally don't cater for multiple standards compliant implementations - if you use any of the methods that Microsoft has labelled with "* Denotes an extension to the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) DOM." in Microsoft's implementation, then you're not using the DOM standard.

Comment: I don't think DOM being language-neutral interface relates to the fact which java interfaces org.w3c.dom library implements. For example, Microsofts MSXML DOM has [IXMLDOMDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd892951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [IXMLDOMDocument2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms761358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IXMLDOMDocument3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces that supplement each other and add extensions to the DOM specification.

Comment: In short: AFAIK there's no reason mandated by the specification that would prevent java adding java-specific interfaces such as Iterable in org.w3c.dom in a similar fashion.

Comment: @eis Added my response to the answer above

Comment: Hm, ok. So apparently the java bindings *are* provided by the standard, in the appendix, so you're right. You could use [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/java-language-binding.html) link in the answer to refer to them.